# How can I create a user who could only create tables and can't delete/drop them

Tags: postgresql, permissions

There's my problem. I'm using PostgreSQL and tried so many things to create a user who can create tables but can't drop them, it's like create a table but assign it to another user. I've tried one trigger but it can't solve my problem.

I've used a trigger that I found on another site, just changed the role where the owner of the table need to be replaced but it didn't work. When I try to create a table with another user it returns me a message

> ERROR: must be a member of role "adm"

This is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_create_set_owner()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  obj record;
BEGIN
  FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag='CREATE TABLE' LOOP
    EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s OWNER TO adm', obj.object_identity);
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_set_owner
 ON ddl_command_end
 WHEN tag IN ('CREATE TABLE')
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_create_set_owner();
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) says,

> To alter the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new owning role, and that role must have `CREATE` privilege on the table's schema. (These restrictions enforce that altering the owner doesn't do anything you couldn't do by dropping and recreating the table. However, a superuser can alter ownership of any table anyway.)

You need to either run execute `CREATE TABLE` as superuser, or create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function (again, as superuser) that creates such tables and assigns their owner roles, then grant the `EXECUTE` privilege on that function *only* to the user in question. See [additional notes on security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY) in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Write an event trigger that throws an error whenever the user tries to drop a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_drop_table() RETURNS event_trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF current_user = 'myuser' THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'you may not drop tables';
   END IF;
END;$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER no_drop_table ON sql_drop WHEN TAG IN ('DROP TABLE')
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE no_drop_table();
```